# rxjs combining 2 objects together from 2 different observables

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have 2 observables that are listening for a database call respectively.  I need to merge the 2 arrays together. If I have the following arrays

```
array1 = [{id: 1, content1: "string"}, {id: 2, content2: "string"}, {id: 3, content3: "string"}]
array2 = [{id: 1, contentX: "string"}, {id: 2, contentY: "string"}, {id: 3, contentZ: "string"}]
```

I want to merge them together so that I get a single observable array like this:

```
[{id:1, content1:"string", contentX:"string"}, {id:2, content2:"string", contentY:"string"}, {id:3, content3:"string", contentZ:"string"}]
```

I have some code but I'm really confused on how to proceed, I can't seem to find the right operators or chain them properly, does anyone have a good explanation on how to proceed? This is what I have so far, but literally don't know how to go on.

```
    const observable1 = getDataFromDb1();
    const observable2= getDataFromDb2();

    observable1 .pipe(
        combineLatest(observable2),
        flatMap(x => {
            //what to do here???
        })
    ).subscribe(
        (value)=>{
            console.log(value);
        }
    )
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: Rx.Observable.merge(observable1, observable2).subscribe(x => console.log(x));

Comment: is your observable emitting an array `[{id: 1, content1: "string"}]` or an object `{id: 1, content1: "string"}`?

Comment: Can you describe how `observable1` and `observable2` emit their values (individually or all in one go)? And how is the relationship defined? Will there always be a *id matching* record in both sets? What should happen if their isn't?

Comment: observable1 and 2 are http calls to 2 different databases @Yoshi. So the results will come at different time from 2 different locations. There will always be an id matching

Comment: @CozyAzure when I console log the emitting array it comes as an array of objects

Comment: @Sivvio Check out my answer then, I think it should help, as long as both sources emit bulks of data. If instead only single elements are emitted I would need to change the answer.

Comment: Yup checking it, but having difficulties with combineLatest, for some reason it doesn't think it's a function. I will investigate and then run your code and try to understand it step by step. I appreciate your time @Yoshi

Comment: @Sivvio Note that I'm importing `combineLatest` as a constructor not an operator. Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: @Yoshi t was. I was importing it as an operator. Although would you mind to explain what's going on? The debugger just skips everything and consoles the results immediately

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174233/discussion-between-yoshi-and-sivvio).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm taking a wild guess here, and assume that both source-observables emit their values in one big chunk. If that's the case, you simply want to `map` both emissions to a *custom merged* one (otherwise please leave a comment). E.g.:

```js
const { of, combineLatest } = rxjs;
const { map } = rxjs.operators;

// simple merge-by-id
const mergeById = ([t, s]) => t.map(p => Object.assign({}, p, s.find(q => p.id === q.id)));

const db1$ = of([
  {id: 1, content1: 'string'},
  {id: 2, content2: 'string'},
  {id: 3, content3: 'string'},
]);

const db2$ = of([
  {id: 1, contentX: 'string'},
  {id: 2, contentY: 'string'},
  {id: 3, contentZ: 'string'},
]);

const all$ = combineLatest(db1$, db2$).pipe(
  map(mergeById)
);

all$.subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.2.1/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested 3 ways of doing this:

```
const entityList1 = [{id: 1, name: 'Bob'}, {id: 2, name: 'John'}, {id: 3, name: 'Mike'}];
const entityList2 = [{id: 3, age: 22}, {id: 1, age: 25}, {id: 2, age: 20}];
```

Same version of @Yoshi:

```
// V0
console.time('V0')
const mergeListsById_v0 = combineLatest(of(entityList1), of(entityList2)).pipe(
  map(([t, s]) => t.map(p => Object.assign({}, p, s.find(q => p.id === q.id))))
).subscribe(x => {
  console.log('result V0:', x);
  console.timeEnd('V0')
});
```

Version using rxjs reduce operator:

```
// V1
console.time('V1')
const mergeListsById_v1 = merge(from(entityList1), from(entityList2)).pipe(
  reduce((entitiesById, entity) => {
    return {
      ...entitiesById,
      [entity.id]: {
        ...entitiesById[entity.id] || {},
        ...entity
      }
    };
  }, {}),
  map(entitiesById => Object.values(entitiesById)),
).subscribe(x => {
  console.log('result V1:', x);
  console.timeEnd('V1')
});
```

Version using the rxjs groupBy operator:

```
// V2
console.time('V2')
const mergeListsById_v2 = merge(from(entityList1), from(entityList2)).pipe(
  groupBy(entity => entity.id),
  mergeMap(groupedEntities$ => groupedEntities$.pipe(
    reduce((merged, entity) => ({...merged, ...entity}), {}))
  ),
  toArray()
).subscribe(x => {
  console.log('result V2:', x);
  console.timeEnd('V2')
});
```

You can play with these version here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-6aqjf9?devtoolsheight=60

As you can see, in terms of performance, the V2 in much better than the others.